# Per-view caching for get_queryset method in a class-based view (Django app)

Tags: python, django

**TL;DR:**

I can't seem to apply **per-view caching** to a class-based view's `get_queryset` method. Is there any alternative way I can use to apply caching to a class-based view's method? Or, is there no way at all?

Currently, the error I'm getting is: *'View' object has no attribute 'method'.* If I write the same decorator on top of the view, I get: *'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'* (traceback below).

---

**Details:**

Here's the view:

```
#@cache_page(20)
class OnlineView(ListView):
    template_name = "online.html"
    paginate_by = 75

    #@cache_page(20)   
    def get_queryset(self):
        users = Session.objects.filter(last_activity__gte=(timezone.now()-timedelta(minutes=5))).only('user').distinct('user')
        return users
```

Here's the traceback I get when I write the caching tag **on top of the view**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 63, in <module>
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 51, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 467, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 311, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 263, in _populate
    for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/hassan/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/hassan/Desktop/unconnectedredditpk/unconnectedreddit/urls.py", line 26, in <module>
    url(r'^online/$', auth(OnlineView.as_view()), name='online'),
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Lastly, here's the pertinent thing I have in **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^online/$', auth(OnlineView.as_view()), name='online'),
```

Comment: `cache_page()` is to cache a _view_, not an individual method.

Comment: Already tried that. It gives me the error: `function` object has no attribute `as_view`

Comment: What have you tried? I can't tell you too much without some code and a traceback.

Comment: I have a class-based ListView, and a simple one liner get_queryset method. I've tried pasting the caching decorator over each of them. I'll edit the question to show you the code and the traceback, hang on.

Comment: Did you read how to [decorate class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)? I guess you get that error because you decorate the class itself, and the decorator returns a function which does not have an `as_view()` method.

Comment: No I was homed in on per-view decorators, I missed method decorators. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier for you to achieve this by [adding the caching in your URL config](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf):

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

url(r'^online/$', cache_page(20)(auth(OnlineView.as_view())), name='online'),
```

However I notice you have an `auth()` decorator on the same view. I'm not sure you want to be caching a view that requires authentication...

Comment: A ton of authenticated users are pinging that URL again and again, which is causing some pretty big spikes in request queuing in my new relic. Now I understand I can (and should) do other optimizations to improve performance as well, but shouldn't caching the said view also be on top of my list?

Comment: It depends what is in the view! If you cache it blindly then Django will serve the same cached content to every user. Presumably the reason the view requires authentication is because it is displaying private content specific to the user.

Comment: I have a web-based public chat app; this view shows users who else is online. I require authentication before I show the data, BUT it's site-wide data that everyone sees the same.

Comment: cache_page will not respect your auth requirement. Sounds like you need to use lower level caching API inside your view methods, or [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching).

Comment: Actually, I'm already using template fragment caching currently (and it works fine). I felt caching my view methods would be more efficient (e.g. caching get_queryset() view method in my case). But that gives me an error I wrote in my question upstairs.

Comment: I suppose method decorators would do the trick, no? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views